# Taylor Series Expansion for variance?

Tags: taylor-expansion, variance

I see that the [first derivative of variance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2836083/derivative-of-the-variance-wrt-x-i), wrt $x_i$ is $\frac{2}{N}(x_i - \mu)$. And the second derivative would be simply $\frac{2}{N}$ (beyond this, all subsequent derivatives should be zero.)

So Should the Taylor Series Expansion simply include these two terms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally if you take the Taylor series of a multivariate function you will invoke all of the partial derivatives, including the cross-term ones (e.g. $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}$).

However, broadly you are correct - the variance is purely quadratic in the $x_i$ terms, so if you take its Taylor series you will get back the exact same quadratic polynomial. And because the quadratic doesn't actually include any cross-multiplied terms, the second derivatives $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}$ only exist when $i = j$ anyway.